# Adding Class Properties based on Generic

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add types to a working javascript class. The class in question takes in an Object of classes, creates instances of the values then stores them to the class itself. The typescript looks something like this:

```
class FancyClass<N extends Record<string, BaseClass> {
    // TODO: Add more keys
    [P in N]: InstanceType<N[P]>;

    constructor(classes: N) {
        for (const [name, NestClass] of Object.entries(classes)) {
            this[name] = new NestClass();
        }
    }
}
```

It becomes very useful to another function as an extension then passing the classes as the Object instead of defining them separately:

```
class RealClass extends FancyClass {
    constructor() {
        base({
            classA: ClassA,
        });
    }

    otherMethods() { }
}

const fancy = new RealClass();
fancy.otherMethods();
fancy.propA.method();
```

I have been able to accomplish this functionally but it changing a lot of established implementation. It would look like this:

```
function withFancy<N extends Record<string, BaseClass>>(
    baseClass: BaseClass & InstanceTypes<N>,
    props: N
): BaseClass & InstanceTypes<N> { }
```

I've also tried mixins but it doesn't seem to be the solution. How can I add these generic properties to a class?

Solution adapted by @Dimava

```
function withProps<N extends FancyOptions>(props: N) {
    return class MiddleClass extends FancyClass<N> {
        constructor(...args) {
            super(props, ...args);
        }
    } as new (name: string, options: any) => BaseClass & InstanceTypes<N>;
}
export class RealClass extends withProps({ c: NestedClass }) { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare class having constructor return your instance type, roughly like this:

```
function declareWith<Class extends abstract new (...args: any) => any, T>(cls: Class) {
    return cls as any as Omit<Class, never> & (new (...a: ConstructorParameters<Class>) => InstanceType<Class> & T)
}

class A {
    #private!: any;
    get x() { return 1 }
}
class B extends declareWith<typeof A, { a: 1 }>(A) {
    f() {
        this.a
        this.x
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice use of a factory to provide the extends class, I hadn't thought of that. This got me on the right track.
I had to provide some constructor args I didn't detail before but it's working so well. Instead of just returning the `cls`, I ended up defining a new "middleware" class and passed the props to the super that way. tyvm!